# Define and throw a dedicated exception instead of using a generic one

Tags: java, exception, sonarqube

SonarQube is complaining about RuntimeException:
"Define and throw a dedicated exception instead of using a generic one".

How can I solve this in an elegant way?

```
 public class ExceptionDefinition<T extends Throwable> {

    private final String id;
    private final MessageFormat format;
    private final Class<T> exceptionClass;

    public ExceptionDefinition( String id, Class<T> exceptionClass, String format ) {
        this.id = id;
        this.exceptionClass = exceptionClass;
        this.format = new MessageFormat( format );
    }

    public T create( Object... parameters ) throws T {
        try {
            final Constructor<T> constructor = exceptionClass.getConstructor( String.class );
            final T exception = constructor.newInstance( generateMessage( parameters ) );
            fillInStackDetails( exception );
            return exception;
        } catch ( InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | IllegalArgumentException | InvocationTargetException | NoSuchMethodException | SecurityException e ) {
            throw new RuntimeException( "An exception was thrown while creating exception", e );
        }
    }

    private String generateMessage( Object... parameters ) {
        return String.format( "%s - %s", id, format.format( parameters ) );
    }

    private void fillInStackDetails( T exception ) {
        final StackTraceElement[] stackTrace = Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace();
        if ( stackTrace.length > 3 ) {
            final StackTraceElement[] newTrace = Arrays.copyOfRange( stackTrace, 3, stackTrace.length );
            exception.setStackTrace( newTrace );
        }
    }
}
```

UPDATE:

```
public class Exceptions {

    public static final ExceptionDefinition<RabbitMQException> UnableToCreateTargetDirectory = new ExceptionDefinition<>( "RBB001", RabbitMQException.class, "Unable to create target directory {0}" );
    public static final ExceptionDefinition<RabbitMQException> UnableToWriteOnTargetDirectory = new ExceptionDefinition<>( "RBB002", RabbitMQException.class, "Target directory {0} is not writeable" );
    ...
}
```

Custom Exception:

```
public class RabbitMQException extends RuntimeException {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 888888888888888286L;

    public RabbitMQException( String message ) {
        super( message );
    }

    public RabbitMQException( String message, Throwable cause ) {
        super( message, cause );
    }
}
```

Usage of the custom exceptions:

```
private void startConsumer( final RabbitConsumerBuilder consumerBuilder ) {
        if ( connection == null ) {
            // log
            throw Exceptions.NoConnection.create();
        }
        ...
}
```

Comment: use `new IllegalStateException` instead of `new RuntimeException`. Why do you declare `throws T`?

Comment: Just curious, why would you use exceptions this way?

Comment: Right, thanks. Because I use this class to generate a bunch of static exceptions with unique codes to be queried on elastiksearch. Furthermore I need to avoid the stacktrace to be too verbose.

Comment: @wero if you add your comment as an answer I'll mark it as accepted

Comment: @GaSacchi one cannot add answers to questions marked as duplicates. Anyway thanks for the offer and good luck with your project